# get inserted rows after merge statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following code. I know it should be done with stored procedure but for our project I have to cheat a bit cause it is needed to get 1 output and it should be selected with another select statement, so table function will do the job when using pragma autonomous_transaction.

the issue is when the merge statement insert at least one row it should be in the SQL%ROWCOUNT and that should be returned as output but it still return 0 and exception is not raised.
Why is that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_fn(
  p_val NUMBER
) RETURN merge_tab
IS
  col_1_idx VARCHAR2(50) := 'col_1_idx';
  teilenummer_trim_idx VARCHAR2(50) := 'teilenummer_trim_idx';
  v_merge_tab merge_tab := merge_tab();
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

IF p_val = 1 THEN
    MERGE INTO table1 x
    USING (SELECT col_1, col_2  FROM table2) y
    ON (x.col_1  = y.col_1)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(x.col_1, x.col_1  )  
    VALUES(y.col_1, y.col_1  );


   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || col_1_idx || ' REBUILD'; -- is needed to rebuild after merging?

    
    COMMIT;
    
    v_merge_tab.EXTEND;
    v_merge_tab(v_merge_tab.LAST) := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   
END IF;    
    RETURN v_merge_tab;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_merge_tab.EXTEND;
        v_merge_tab(v_merge_tab.LAST) := 0;
        RETURN v_merge_tab;
END;
```

Comment: *is needed to rebuild after merging?* No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL%ROWCOUNT should be *calculated* right after MERGE (and index doesn't need to be rebuilt after each merge you do):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_fn(
  p_val NUMBER
) RETURN merge_tab
IS
  col_1_idx VARCHAR2(50) := 'col_1_idx';
  teilenummer_trim_idx VARCHAR2(50) := 'teilenummer_trim_idx';
  v_merge_tab merge_tab := merge_tab();
  l_count number;                                  --> this
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

IF p_val = 1 THEN
    MERGE INTO table1 x
    USING (SELECT col_1, col_2  FROM table2) y
    ON (x.col_1  = y.col_1)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(x.col_1, x.col_1  )  
    VALUES(y.col_1, y.col_1  );

    l_count := sql%rowcount;                       --> this
   
    -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || col_1_idx || ' REBUILD'; -- is needed to rebuild after merging?
       
    COMMIT;
    
    v_merge_tab.EXTEND;
    v_merge_tab(v_merge_tab.LAST) := l_count;     --> this
   
END IF;    
    RETURN v_merge_tab;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_merge_tab.EXTEND;
        v_merge_tab(v_merge_tab.LAST) := 0;
        RETURN v_merge_tab;
END;
```